# Sum and square root list elements

Tags: prolog

So I am currently trying to compute a formula using Prolog. I currently have part of the formula done, but I am having trouble implementing the next part where I need to add the elements of the list and then square root the sum. Not sure how I would do that.

What I currently have:

```
formula([], [], []).
formula([], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
  L = H2,
  formula([], T2, Ls).
formula([H1|T1], [], [L|Ls]) :-
  L = H1,
  formula(T1, [], Ls).
formula([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
  L is (H1 - H2)*(H1 - H2),
  formula(T1, T2, Ls).
```

Comment: Write `L is (H1-H2)^2` instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original formula

```
formula([], [], []).
formula([], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
  L = H2,
  formula([], T2, Ls).
formula([H1|T1], [], [L|Ls]) :-
  L = H1,
  formula(T1, [], Ls).
formula([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [L|Ls]) :-
  L is (H1 - H2)*(H1 - H2),
  formula(T1, T2, Ls).
```

can be simplified to make the pattern matching more explicit:

```
formula( []     , []     , []     ) .
formula( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs] ) :- formula( [] , Ys , Zs ) .
formula( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Zs] ) :- formula( Xs , [] , Zs ) .
formula( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [Z|Zs] ) :-
  L is ( X - Y ) * ( X - Y ) ,
  formula(Xs,Ys,Zs)
  .
```

I assume your instructor wants you to roll your own here and learn about recursion rather than using a built-in predicate. So, ... You *could* sum the elements of a list like this (the naive implementation):

```
sum_of( [] , 0 ) .      % the sum of the empty list is zero.
sum_of( [X|Xs] , S ) :- % the sum of an empty list is computed by
  sum(Xs,T) ,           % - computing the sum of the tail of the list
  S is T+X              % - and adding that to the value of the head of the list.
  .                     %
```

But that will fail with a stack overflow once the list gets sufficiently long as each recursive call pushes a new frame onto the stack. Prolog has an nifty optimization (*tail recursion optimization*) that effectively converts recursion into iteration by recognizing when it can reuse the stack frame. To do that, the recurive call must be the very last thing done.

This introduces a common pattern in prolog programming:

- a public interface predicate (here, `sum_of/2`),
- that invokes a "private" tail-recursize worker predicate (here, `sum_of/3`) that uses an *accumulator* argument to build up its result.

Using that pattern, we get this implementation:

```
 sum_of(Xs,Sum) :- sum_of(Xs,0,Sum) .

 sum_of( []     , S , S ) .  % the sum of the empty list is 0.
 sum_of( [X|Xs] , T , S ) :- % the sum of a non-empty list is computed by
   T1 is T+X ,               % incrementing the accumulator by the value of the head of the list, and
   sum_of( Xs , T1 , S )     % recursing down on the tail.
   .                         % Easy!
```

This will work for lists of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SWI-Prolog library predicate `sum_list/2`:

```
list_summed_and_square_rooted(List, Value) :-
    sum_list(List, Sum),
    Value is sqrt(Sum).
```

You probably don't need to write a separate predicate for relating a list to the square root of the sum of its elements, unless you'll be needing to use that particular relation often. Your `formula/3` makes one list out of two, but ultimately you seem to be after a numerical value, so you probably *do* want another predicate to describe the relation between two lists and the resultant numerical value.

```
lists_processed_in_some_way(List1, List2, Value) :-
    formula(List1, List2, CombinedList),
    sum_list(CombinedList, Sum),
    Value is sqrt(Sum).
```

---

By the way, you can simplify your `formula/3` because you don't need `L = H2`:

```
formula([], [H2|T2], [H2|Ls]) :-
    formula([], T2, Ls).
```

Also, it's generally good practice to name your predicates carefully, with something descriptive. It will help you reason about what your predicates do and help you communicate your programs to others.

Comment: Sorry im new to prolog. Would i insert that into my current function or make it into its own seperate function.

Comment: @user3281114 No problem. I'll expand my answer to indicate usage, but I don't have time now. FYI: in Prolog we work with *predicates* not *functions*. This is not merely a matter of technical terminology: functions can be *evaluated* and 'replaced' with their output. In languages that work with functions, we could have written the body of `list_summed_and_square_rooted/2` thus: `Value = sqrt(sum_list(List))`. then the value returned by `sum_list` would be passed to `sqrt` and assigned to `Value`.  In Prolog, with some few, explicitly marked exceptions, predicates only 'return' truth-value.

Comment: Note that `sum_list/2` is not a *standard* predicate but it might be available *depending on the Prolog system* as a *library* predicate.

Comment: @user3281114 Finally had a chance to make additions. Let me know if you still have questions!